# Spring Boot fails to start - There is a circular dependency between beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I created Spring Boot application using configuration class. It is usual RestAPI using spring library. Inside it I use my own Logger class to log every action.

Also, I include application.properties in my Application class where is main function. No beans in xml - everything only in that Configuration class.

Here is that configuration:

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

@Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
private String dialect;
@Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
private String showSql;
@Value("${hibernate.mappingResources}")
private String[] mappingResources;
@Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}")
private String driverClassName;
@Value("${jdbc.url}")
private String url;
@Value("${jdbc.username}")
private String username;
@Value("${jdbc.password}")
private String password;

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
@Autowired
private LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean;

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", showSql);
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
    sessionFactoryBean.setMappingResources(mappingResources);
    return sessionFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    dataSource.setUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUsername(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    return dataSource;
}

}
```

Also, I created logger class:

```
@Service
public class LinksLogger {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLogs");

// methods here...

}
```

Here how I use my logger:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class HelloController {

@Autowired
private LinksLogger logger;

@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Map<String, String> hello() {
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("data", "Hello#_#World");
    logger.log("Hello#_#World");
    return data;
}
}
```

Looks like okey, right?
But when I compile my code I got exception:

```
There is a circular dependency between 2 beans in the application context:
- helloController (field private com.defaultxyz.linksapi.util.LinksLogger com.defaultxyz.linksapi.controller.HelloController.logger)
- applicationConfiguration (field private org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean com.defaultxyz.linksapi.util.ApplicationConfiguration.localSessionFactoryBean)
- localSessionFactoryBean
```

Why this exception appears? What I did wrong in code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to @Autowire beans in a class where they are instantiated.

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
@Autowired
private LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean;
```

But you also define these as @Bean, the container cannot inject them in the autowired fields since they are created in the same class. Remove the @Autowired fields and instead use the methods where needed.

```
sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
```

instead of

```
sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
```